# How do I access stored data after pulling data with Selenium and exporting to python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to extract a value from a web page (specifically a value from a table). I used Selenium IDE to buid the base of the code for this process, then I exported it to Python, and it isn't working anymore. I haven't been able to access the data that was supposed to have been pulled during the Selenium tasks.
I put what I have so far below.

```
class TestPulldata():


def setup_method(self, method):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    self.vars = {}
  
  def teardown_method(self, method):
    self.driver.quit()
  
  def test_pulldata(self):
    self.driver.get("http://ailab-projects1.ist.psu.edu:8080/bcpred/predict.html")
    self.driver.find_element(By.NAME, "sequence").send_keys("msdngpqsnqrsapritfggptdstdnnqnggrngarpkqrrpqglpnntaswftaltqhgkeelrfprgqgvpintnsgpddqigyyrratrrvrggdgkmkelsprwyfyylgtgpeaslpygANKEGIVWVATEGALntpkdhigtrnpnnnaatvlqlpqgttlpkgfyaegsrggsqassrsssrsrgnsrnstpgssrgnsparmasgggetalalllldrlnqleskvsgkgqqqqgqtvtkksaaeaskkprqkrtatkqynvtqafgrrgpeqtqgnfgdqdlirqgtdykhwpqiaqfapsasaffgmsrigmevtpsgtwltyhgaiklddkdpqfkdnvillnkhidayktfpptepkkdkkkktdeaqplpqrqkkqptvtllpaadmddfsrqlqnsmsgasadstqa")
    dropdown = self.driver.find_element(By.NAME, "length")
    dropdown.find_element(By.XPATH, "//option[. = '14']").click()
    dropdown = self.driver.find_element(By.NAME, "specificity")
    dropdown.find_element(By.XPATH, "//option[. = '65']").click()
    self.driver.find_element(By.NAME, "submit").click()
    self.vars["output"] = self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(3)").texte here
```